# Compute AIC of Linear Mixed-Effects Model by Hand

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, aic

The Akaike Information Criterion (AIC) quantifies a model's goodness of fit while also taking into account the model's degrees of freedom. In R, there is a function called `AIC` with which the AIC of a variety of different models can be computed. I'm interested in the question of how the AIC for a linear mixed-effects model can be computed by hand.

I manage to manually compute the AIC of a linear regression, e.g.:

```
lm1 = lm(mpg ~ wt, data=mtcars)
AIC(lm1) # =166.0294
nrow(mtcars)*(log(2*pi)+1+log((sum(lm1$residuals^2)/nrow(mtcars))))  + 2*(length(lm1$coefficients)+1) # =166.0294
```

Can somebody tell me how I would compute the AIC of a LMM by hand, e.g.:

```
library(lme4)
lmm1 = lmer(mpg ~ wt + (1|am), data=mtcars)
AIC(lmm1) # =164.9892
```

Comment: `2*(6 + logLik(lmm1))`

Comment: How to compute the ```logLik``` by hand?

Comment: @hyhno01 Forget it. You should extract the "REML criterion at optimum" from the model object and the log-likelihood is then a simple transformation of that. See the code of `lme4:::logLik.merMod`. Remember, the likelihood is what is actually maximized. In ordinary least squares that is equivalent to minimizing the sum of squares but for a more complex model with REML estimation there is nothing that simple.

Comment: @Roland There must be an algorithm maximizing the likelihood. It might be complex. Nevertheless I would to understand how it works for the above (rather simple) example.

Comment: I guess you should start with the "Computational Methods" vignette: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html